# How to intercept the submit button written in javascript with isset php

Tags: javascript, php

First of all thanks to any user of the site for taking the time to answer my question.

Basically the goal of my question as the title suggests is to intercept the submission of the form written in javascript using the classic php isset

code:

```
        <form action="" id="regForm" name="NOME_FORM"   method="post" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/grow-it' )  ); ?>">
            <h1>Register:</h1>
            <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
            <?php foreach ( $grow as $risultato )
            {
                $username = $risultato->username;
                $insta = "https://www.instagram.com/".$username; ?>
                <div class="tab">

                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $insta; ?>" type="button" id="doStuffBtn" onclick="doStuff()">
                        Followe <?php echo $username; ?> per andare avanti
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
            }?>
    </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="overflow:auto;">
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>

                        <button type="button" name="nextBtn" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
                <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                    <?php foreach ( $grow as $risultato ) {?>
                        <span class="step"></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>s
    </form>
```

js:

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

var nextAvailable = false;

function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function doStuff(n) {
    nextAvailable = true;
}

function nextPrev(n) {
    if (nextAvailable || n < 0) {
        nextAvailable = false;

        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }
}

function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
}
```

try to intercept:

```
if(isset($_POST["nextBtn"]) && $_POST["nextBtn"] == "submit")
    {
       ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "www.google.com"
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

how could i solve?
thanks in advance

how to invoke form submission in php

Comment: As you've pointed out, the submit button isn't used to submit the form (JS is) so the submit button isn't in the form data. So don't look for the submit button. Look for something else.

Comment: php is server side and is executed before the page is served to the browser, js is executed after. How do you expect to bind php and js in your page?

Comment: Taking a step back for a moment... Is the *only* action being performed by this server-side code this (somewhat clunky) redirect?  If so then you can skip the problem entirely and just do that client-side.  If this is just a (partially) simplified example and there is additional need to post the form to the server, since the JavaScript is invoking that form post then the JavaScript code could first add a hidden element to the form and the server-side code could check for that instead of the button.

Comment: also, if you want to learn something, learn how to change the location directly in PHP instead of injecting the js like you do now.

Comment: @David certainly the task of php, is not the one transcribed, the code you see is just to simplify everything as an example. Meanwhile thanks for your words, how could I do this in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button isn't submitting the form, the JavaScript code is.  So the button won't have a value included in the form submission.

However, what you *can* do is use the JavaScript code to add a form value just before the form submission.  Then the server-side code can check for *that* value.  For example, consider this:

```
// add a new form element:
let el = document.createElement("input");
el.type = "hidden";
el.name = "clickedNext";
el.value = "submit";
document.getElementById("regForm").appendChild(el);
```

This would add to the form an element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="clickedNext" value="submit">
```

Simply include that logic *right before* whatever operation in your JavaScript code submits the form.

Then in your server-side code you can check for *that* element:

```
if(isset($_POST["clickedNext"]) && $_POST["clickedNext"] == "submit")
```

Comment: i can't use the code because this piece, it s not write well.....    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;    ---> return false it s the problem

Comment: @user21397959: That part was copied/pasted *verbatim* from your code.  Technically it isn't relevant to the answer, so if you don't like that part then I've removed it.  But the overall point remains the same.  If you're submitting the form via JavaScript then, just before doing that, you can add an element to the form.  Whatever you're doing which *already works* to submit the form, you can go ahead and add the new form element just before doing that.  (If, on the other hand, something in your code *isn't working* with regards to submitting the form, that's a new and separate question.)